# Parametric representation of the motion of a particle in context of kruskal coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In "N. Straumann - General Relativity" talking about the Kruskal continuation of the Schwarschild solution it is considered for radial timelike geodesic the following:
$$d\tau=(\frac{2m}{r}-\frac{2m}{R})^{\frac{-1}{2}}dr$$
with the following parametric solution:
$$r=\frac{R}{2}(1+\cos{\eta})$$
$$\tau=(\frac{R^3}{8m})^{\frac{1}{2}}(\eta+\sin{\eta})$$
I would like to verify these parametric representation of the motion. So I have computed
$$dr=-\frac{R}{2}\sin{\eta}d\eta$$
$$d\tau=(\frac{R^3}{8m})^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+\cos{\eta})d\eta$$
And so I should have:
$$(\frac{R^3}{8m})^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+\cos{\eta})d\eta=-\Big(\frac{2m}{\frac{R}{2}(1+\cos{\eta})}-\frac{2m}{R}\Big)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\frac{R}{2}\sin{\eta}d\eta$$
So from this seems that the identity does not hold...thus I am doing some mistakes. Can you help me?

Comment: Look at the link that @cely has written in the comments of the answer below

Comment: The image of the page with this solution from the book cited is shown on https://archive.org/details/GeneralRelativity/page/n202/mode/1up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think it should be

$$\text{d}\tau = -\left(\frac{r_s}{r}-\frac{r_s}{R}\right)^{-\frac 12}\text{d}r$$

with $r_s = 2M$.
This would be consistent for an infalling motion with the changes in the proper time and radius when compared to the changes in the parameter $\eta\,$ ($\text{d}r <0$ while we want $\text{d}\tau > 0$).
With this, you can show that the parametrization is indeed equal.
One has

\begin{align*}\left(\frac{r_s}{r}-\frac{r_s}{R}\right)^{-\frac 12} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{r_s}}\left(\frac{1-\frac 12 (1+\cos\eta)}{\frac R2 (1+\cos\eta)}\right)^{-\frac 12} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{r_s}} \left(\frac{\frac 12 - \frac 12 \cos\eta}{\frac R2 (1+\cos\eta)}\right)^{-\frac 12} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{R}{r_s}} \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\eta}{1-\cos\eta}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{R}{r_s}} \frac{1}{\tan \frac \eta 2}
\end{align*}

Plugging this in leads to

\begin{align*}
\text{d}\tau &= -\left(\frac{r_s}{r}-\frac{r_s}{R}\right)^{-\frac 12}\text{d}r \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{R}{r_s}} \frac{1}{\tan \frac \eta 2} \frac{R}{2}\sin\eta \text{d}\tau \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{R^3}{4r_s}} \frac{\sin\eta}{\tan \frac \eta 2}\text{d}\eta
\end{align*}

Notice that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin\eta}{\tan \frac \eta 2} &= \sin\eta \frac{\cos \frac \eta 2}{\sin \frac \eta 2} \\
&= 2\sin\frac \eta 2\,\cos\frac \eta 2\, \frac{\cos \frac \eta 2}{\sin \frac \eta 2} \\
&= 2\,\cos^2\frac \eta 2 \\
&= 2 \left(\frac{1+\cos\eta}{2}\right) \\
&= 1+\cos\eta
\end{align*}

Hence

\begin{equation*}
\text{d}\tau = \sqrt{\frac{R^3}{4r_s}} (1+\cos\eta)\text{d}\eta = \left(\frac{R^3}{8m}\right)^{\frac 12} (1+\cos\eta) \text{d}\eta
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there is no that minus sign, I have just checked it now on the book!

Comment: Look here https://books.google.it/books?id=5iH4CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=motion+cycloid+kruskal&source=bl&ots=o-Q3TNgYSE&sig=ACfU3U0EQeII3-kodmJHTkd0cwA8X2szvA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRyf7ymbfvAhWGCuwKHde4BFoQ6AEwAXoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=motion%20cycloid%20kruskal&f=false

Comment: He is taking the square root, so you are free to add the minus sign. It is pretty much just a matter of consistency. I am pretty sure he is just missing the minus sign, which is needed for the same reason I stated in my answer.

Comment: But why if this works only with the minus sign the book does not choose the minus sign? So strange...

Comment: Because strictly speaking you have to consider the absolute value since you take the square root of the expression.. Then the minus sign does not matter actually.

Comment: So by what you have stated in your answer, by a physical point of view it is reasonable the minus sign?

Comment: Exactly. Consequently you also don't have to care about absolute values as well in that case.

Comment: There are two branches for $dr/d\tau$ and they can be parametrized as shown in the book, but with appropriate sign.